# how to display random que without repeating?

Tags: php

i want to display the Questions from the database for online aptitude test.
i generate code to display 10 question randomly.

**but major problem is Question is repeating.
i don't want repeated question in question paper.**

here is a code for display question randomly:-

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="./eval.php" method="post">
<?php

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost" ,"root","");

mysql_select_db("aptitude");



 for ( $i = 1; $i < 11; ++$i )
{

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `main`  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ");




 while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)):

    $q = $rows['Q_no'];
    $qus = $rows['Question'];
    $a = $rows['answer1'];
    $b = $rows['answer2'];
    $c = $rows['answer3'];
    $d = $rows['answer4'];
    $ans = $rows['correct'];

     echo "Q$i:-$qus <br>";
    echo "A <input type=radio name = 'answer[$q]' value = '$a'></input>$a &nbsp &nbsp"; 
    echo "B <input type=radio name = 'answer[$q]' value = '$b'></input>$b &nbsp &nbsp"; 
    echo "C <input type=radio name = 'answer[$q]' value = '$c'></input>$c &nbsp &nbsp "; 
    echo "D <input type=radio name = 'answer[$q]' value = '$d'></input>$d <br><br> ";


    endwhile;

 }


?>

<center><input name="cmdSubmit" type="submit" id="cmdSubmit" value="Submit"/>
</center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: store answer in session and compare it when the user posts back to the form?  Return the Q_no as part of the form, and lookup the correct answer?   There are many options what have you tried so far?

Comment: This is not the first time you've posted the exact same non-question. Either make it a VALID question for this site, or stop posting it.

Comment: @MarcB I think that once my edit is accepted, it will be easier to understand.

Comment: Wanting to find the correct answer on this page is simple...simply `echo $ans`. Now, wanting to find whether or not the user submitted the correct answer...that's different and that's not what you're asking. Please clarify.

Comment: I want code to match user i/p answer with correct answer

Comment: is 'ans' a,b,c,d? or is answer something like "42"?

Answer (score 2):

```
$q = $rows['Q_no'];
$qus = $rows['Que'];
$a = $rows['A'];
$b = $rows['B'];
$c = $rows['C'];
$d = $rows['D'];
$ans=$row['ans'];
```

Just see the above thing:-

You have entered

**$ans=$row['ans'];**

it should be **$ans=$rows['ans'];**
see **$qus**

Answer (score 0):

Taking a stab at this, based on some assumptions from your post.  Please note this is untested, may have bugs, will not be efficient, is probably insecure, etc...

it appears that you are putting 30 random questions on the page, and are looking to test the answers for each  on of them (Your form and your question don't seem to match up 100%, so going by the code).

in the inner loop make your form look like this

```
    echo "Q:-$qus <br>";
    echo "A <input type=radio name = 'answer[$q]' value = '$a'></input>$a &nbsp &nbsp"; 
    echo "B <input type=radio name = 'answer[$q]' value = '$b'></input>$b &nbsp &nbsp"; 
    echo "C <input type=radio name = 'answer[$q]' value = '$c'></input>$c &nbsp &nbsp "; 
    echo "D <input type=radio name = 'answer[$q]' value = '$d'></input>$d <br><br> ";
```

Then in your form processing code you can do this.

```
    $answers = $_POST['answer'];
    foreach($answers as $question => $answer){
         $query = mysql_query("SELECT ans FROM `main` where Q_no = $question");
         $result  = mysql_fetch_array($query);
         if ($result['ans']==$answer){
              echo "Question $question was correct <br>";
         }else{
              echo "Question $question was incorrect <br>";
         }
    }
```

what that should do is create an array of answers,  look each one up in the database and see if they are correct (Assuming  ==  can compare the 2).    As I said not very efficient. or elegant but should give you an idea how to proceed.